# php custom parse a string with preg

Tags: php, string, parsing, explode, preg-split

My methods parse strings and do stuff with the information contained in the string.
a simple example would be

```
$string=
"
    user:name,password={$_POST['name']}, {$_POST['password']}(md5); 
    names:name=name;
";
$class->$method($string);
```

The above would do two insert statements. The first will insert in a table named user the users name and the password encypted in md5. 
the second would insert a name in the names table. I'm having setting it up so that characters can be escaped. ie if the users name was p;ez. The string would have p\;ez.
My current method is as follows

```
    #get position of ;
    $offsetSemi=stripos($s, ";");
    #check if its escaped
    if ($s[$offsetSemi-1]!='\\')
    {
        //not escaped
    }
```

the problem with the above method is that it will only check the first instance of ;.
the other solution i tried was exploding the string on ;. however this would not work because it exploded on all instances including ones that were escaped. the other thing i tried was an explode with the regular expression below

```
/[^\\\];/
```

the prolem with this is that it exploded on the charecter before ; on all the instances that were not escaped. is there a way i can explode a string on all instances of ; that are not preceded by a backslash?

Comment: Does your input **have** to be in that convoluted format?  If not, you should consider using a format that has built in parsers like JSON on XML.

Comment: no it does not. I'm not familiar with json or xml. I have heard of them but never had learned or used them up to date. Can you suggest a page that has an example of parsing xml or json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of exploding you can parse the string:

```
$arr = array();
$tmp = "";

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($s); $i++) {
   switch ($s[$i]) {
      case "\\":
         if ($i < strlen($s) - 1) $tmp .= $s[$i++] . $s[$i++];
      break;
      case ";":
         $arr[] = $tmp;
         $tmp = "";
      break;
      default:
         $tmp .= $s[$i];
   }
}

if (strlen(trim($tmp)) > 0) { // last section
    $arr[] = $tmp;
}
```

Comment: stores all but the last section.

Comment: @yamikoWebs: Obviously `$tmp` contains the last section after the `for` loop. Anyway I edited my answer to include the last section in `$arr`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using JSON for you input format.  Since you are using PHP you could check out this [intro to JSON and PHP](http://www.itnewb.com/v/Introduction-to-JSON-and-PHP).  Also, you will need to use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).  With those functions you can easily convert a JSON string to a PHP object or associative array and back again if needed.  There is no need for you to worry about the tokenizing/parsing step if you start with a format that has built in parsing help.

If you want to go with XML then you could use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) or [DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php).  But, you would be best served by using JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Write a parser. Tokenize your input first, then look at it.